# Revert F3 and F4 behavior in byobu?

Tags: 12.04, byobu

With a fresh 12.04 installation of Ubuntu, byobu's interpretation of the function keys seems to have changed.  <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> will still change the active tab on the current session, but it changes it for all connections.  Previously, if you have two active connections to the same user (same session) with User 1 on shell 0/tab 0 and User 2 on shell 0/tab 0, when User 2 pressed <kbd>F3</kbd> , they would be changed to tab 1 while User 1 would remain on tab 0.  With the latest version in 12.04, when User 2 presses <kbd>F3</kbd>, all connected users are moved to shell 1/tab 1.  Is there any way to re-enable the old behavior?  I have looked at the /etc/byobu directory and only found backend and socketdir files there.  Toggling backend between tmux and screen did not seem to render any difference.  Anyone know what, if any, configuration option exist to control this?

Answer (score 1):

12.04 byobu now defaults to `tmux` as a backend instead of `screen`.

So to get the byobu you are used to back, just type:

```
byobu-select-backend
```

and select the "screen" option instead of "tmux".